# Storing words from a file into a string Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need help constructing an array in which it would hold the values of .txt file.

Text file (example):

```
this is the text file.
```

I would want the array to look like:

```
Array[0]:This
Array[1]:is 
etc..
```

Hoping someone can give me a hand, i am familar with how to open, create and read froma text file, but currently that is about it. I do not know how to use/play around with the data once i can read it. This is the could i have constructed so far.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class file {

private Scanner x;

    public void openFile(){
      try{
        x=new Scanner(new File("note3.txt"));
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not find file"); }}



    public void readFile(){
      String str;

      while(x.hasNext()){
        String a=x.next();

        System.out.println(a);}}

    public void closeFile(){
      x.close();}}
```

Seperate file which reads...

```
    public class Prac33 {


    public static void main(String[] args) { 

     file r =new file();
        r.openFile();
        r.readFile();
        r.closeFile();
      }
    }
```

I am hoping to store these into an array which i can later use to sort the file alphabetically.

Comment: The problem with an array is you'll have to know how many words are in the text file first.  A list would probably work better.

Comment: By sorting the file do you mean by words or by sentences?

Comment: by words, my goal is to sort all the words in the file by alphabetical order, and to delete any repeated words in nessasry. If you receomend approaching the question at a different angle please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of characters does the file have? just `.` and letters?

Comment: it is made up of just words, no number or symbols etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the whole file into a string first, then split it:

```
    ...
    String whole = "";
    while (x.hasNext()) {
        String a = x.next();
        whole = whole + " " + a;
    }
    String[] array = whole.split(" ");
    ...
```

Or you could use an `ArrayList`, which is a 'cleaner' solution:

```
    ...
    ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<>();
    while (x.hasNext()) {
        String a = x.next();
        words.add(a);
    }
    //get an item from the arraylist like this:
    String val=words.get(index);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply i appreciate your time. I tried inserting

Comment: public void readFile(){
    
     ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<>();
    while (x.hasNext()) {
        String a = x.next();
        words.add(a);
    }

Comment: but i get an error" <> operater is not allowed for source level below 1.7"?

Comment: Yes, that is because java below v 1.7 does not allow generic parameter inference. Change new ArrayList<> to new ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 0):

You can add to an `ArrayList` instead of your `System.out.println(a);`.

Then, you can convert the `ArrayList` to a `String array` when you're done using:

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you can do:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class file {

private Scanner x;

public void openFile() {
    try {
        x = new Scanner(new File("note3.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String[] readFile(String[] array) {
    long count = 0;
    while (x.hasNext()) {
        String a = x.next();
        array[(int) count] = a;
        System.out.println(a);
        count++;
    }
    return array;
}

public void closeFile() {
    x.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use

```
new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("file name"));
```

With the object of `bufferedReader` iterate and read lines from the file.  Post that use `StringTokenizer` to tokenise based on `" "` empty space and store them to your `array`.

Comment: `StringTokenizer` has been deprecated for years. `Scanner` is the correct class to use.